# ng-change is not called on ng-selected dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am dynamically selecting an item from `select`. Item is getting selected correctly but `model` is not getting updated. Also, `ng-change` is not getting called in this case.

**Code**:

```
<select id="course" name="course"
        ng-model="courseId"
        ng-change="getBatch(courseId)">
    <option
        ng-repeat="course in courses"
        value="{{course.course_id}}"
        ng-selected="course.course_name == 
                         '<?php echo ($editMode)? $student_data->course_name : ""?>'">
            {{course.course_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**I tried**:

```
setInterval(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 2000);
```

I checked many links, but I did not get answer.

Comment: have you tried using `ng-options`?

Comment: I checked syntax but did not understand it properly. Also I did not get how to replace my code with `ng-options`.

Comment: one question- why you need to integrate AngularJS with PHP? Have you checked that your php part in select option in not breaking html?

Comment: Actually I am updating old code. I am doing it step by step. Nothing is breaking code right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `function` containing code you want to execute in `ng-init`.

```
<select id="course" name="course"
        ng-model="courseId"
        <?php echo $editMode ? 'ng-init="initCourseSelect(' . $student_data->course_id . ')"' : ''?>
        ng-change="getBatch(courseId)">
    <option
        ng-repeat="course in courses"
        value="{{course.course_id}}">
        {{course.course_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.initCourseSelect = function (courseId) {
    console.log("course id ", courseId);
    // set model to be selected on view
    $scope.courseId = courseId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have tried.
I have removed PHP part as it is not configured on my machine.

It working fine

HTML.

```
<select id="course" name="course"
        ng-model="courseId"
        ng-change="getBatch(courseId)">
    <option
        ng-repeat="course in courses"
        value="{{course.course_id}}">
            {{course.course_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

JS

created sample course array as per your html.

```
$scope.courses = [{course_id :112,course_name:'course1'},
      {course_id :15,course_name:'course2' },
      {course_id :11,course_name:'course3' },
      {course_id :14,course_name:'course4' }
      ];

      $scope.getBatch = function(courseId){

        console.log(courseId);

      }
```

Comment: This code is same as mine. Did you check `ng-selected` part?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have php configured on my machine.So,could not checked

Comment: Its ok. I would have tried `ng-selected="course.course_name == 'course3' " `

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `ngOptions` like this:

```
<select id="course" name="course" 
    <?php echo $editMode ? 'ng-init="courseId = ' . $student_data->course_id . '"' : '' ?>
    ng-model="courseId" 
    ng-change="getBatch(courseId)"
    ng-options="course.course_id as course.course_name for course in courses">
</select>
```

Then model should bind properly, providing that PHP `$student` object has also property `course_id`.

Comment: You brought me too close. Can you tell me one more thing? values are rendering as string. How to make them integer?

Comment: Right now it is showing as `<option value="string:1" label="Sixth">Sixth</option>`

Comment: This is because you have course_id as strings in your model. So you have array of objects like `[{course_name: "One", course_id: "1"}]`.

Comment: I used for loop in controller to convert it to int. Now the code is working but  it is not calling ng-change="getBatch(courseId)"

Comment: Post your code if you are asking for help, I have no idea what you are messing with there.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i< response.data.length; i++){
                    response.data[i].course_id = parseInt(response.data[i].course_id);
                }

Comment: I just changed above part to run your code. I did not change anything else.